# Setting up combobox as cell content for TableItems for a few columns in java.swt table

Tags: java, combobox, swt

I am building a table and I am iterating over the "methodtraces2" list to set each row of this table. I would like 4 columns to have a combobox as their cell content. More specifically, I would like the "Callers", "Callees", "CallersExecuted" and "CalleesExecuted" columns to have comboboxes as their cell content. Each entry of the combobox should correspond to the ToString behavior of the element of the adequate list. Each cell within the "Callers" column should be populated with a combobox and each combobox should contain all the entries within `List<Method2Representation>` callers. Similarly, Each cell within the "Callees" column should be populated with a combobox and each combobox should contain all the entries within the `List<Method2Representation>` callees. Same applies to "callersexecuted" and "calleesexecuted". The columns for which I need comboboxes are indicated as comments in the code below, the lists to be used to populate these comboboxes are also indicated as comments within the code below:

```
    shell = new Shell();
    shell.setSize(1500, 1500);
    shell.setText("SWT Application TEST");

    table = new Table(shell, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
    table.setBounds(0, 10, 2000, 2000);
    table.setHeaderVisible(true);
    table.setLinesVisible(true);

    TableColumn tblclmnMethodID = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
    tblclmnMethodID.setWidth(100);
    tblclmnMethodID.setText("MethodID");

    TableCursor tableCursor = new TableCursor(table, SWT.NONE);

    TableColumn tblclmnMethodName = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
    tblclmnMethodName.setWidth(100);
    tblclmnMethodName.setText("MethodName");

    TableColumn tblclmnRequirementID = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
    tblclmnRequirementID.setWidth(153);
    tblclmnRequirementID.setText("RequirementID");

    TableColumn tblclmnRequirementName = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
    tblclmnRequirementName.setWidth(150);
    tblclmnRequirementName.setText("RequirementName");

    TableColumn tblclmnClassID = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
    tblclmnClassID.setWidth(100);
    tblclmnClassID.setText("ClassID");

    TableColumn tblclmnClassName = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
    tblclmnClassName.setWidth(100);
    tblclmnClassName.setText("ClassName");

    TableColumn tblclmnGold = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
    tblclmnGold.setWidth(100);
    tblclmnGold.setText("Gold");

    TableColumn tblclmnSubject = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
    tblclmnSubject.setWidth(100);
    tblclmnSubject.setText("Subject");

    TableColumn tblclmnGoldpredictionCaller = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
    tblclmnGoldpredictionCaller.setWidth(150);
    tblclmnGoldpredictionCaller.setText("GoldPredictionCaller");

    TableColumn tblclmnGoldpredictionCallee = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
    tblclmnGoldpredictionCallee.setWidth(170);
    tblclmnGoldpredictionCallee.setText("GoldPredictionCallee");
    //COMBO BOX NEEDED FOR CALLERS RETRIEVED FROM 
    // List<Method2Representation> callers
    TableColumn tblclmnCallers = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
    tblclmnCallers.setWidth(100);
    tblclmnCallers.setText("Callers");
    //COMBO BOX NEEDED FOR CALLEES RETRIEVED FROM 
    // List<Method2Representation> callees  
    TableColumn tblclmnCallees = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
    tblclmnCallees.setWidth(100);
    tblclmnCallees.setText("Callees");
    //COMBO BOX NEEDED FOR CALLERSEXECUTED RETRIEVED FROM 
    // List<Method2Representation> callersExecuted
    TableColumn tblclmnCallersExecuted = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
    tblclmnCallersExecuted.setWidth(150);
    tblclmnCallersExecuted.setText("CallersExecuted");
    //COMBO BOX NEEDED FOR CALLEESEXECUTED RETRIEVED FROM 
    // List<Method2Representation> calleesExecuted
    TableColumn tblclmnCalleesExecuted = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
    tblclmnCalleesExecuted.setWidth(150);
    tblclmnCalleesExecuted.setText("CalleesExecuted");



    for(MethodTrace2 meth: methodtraces2) {
        TableItem item1 = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
        //callees combobox should populate tblclmnCallees
        List<Method2Representation> callees = meth.getCalleesList(); 
        //callers combobox should populate tblclmnCallers
        List<Method2Representation> callers = meth.getCallersList(); 
        //callersExecuted combobox should populate tblclmnCallersExecuted 
        List<Method2Representation> callersExecuted = meth.getCallersListExecuted(); 
        //calleesExecuted combobox should populate tblclmnCalleesExecuted 
        List<Method2Representation> calleesExecuted = meth.getCalleesListExecuted(); 
        item1.setText(new String[] { meth.MethodRepresentation.getMethodid(), meth.MethodRepresentation.getMethodname(), meth.Requirement.getID(), meth.Requirement.RequirementName, meth.ClassRepresentation.classid, meth.ClassRepresentation.classname, meth.gold
                , meth.subject, meth.goldpredictionCaller, meth.goldpredictionCallee});
    }
```

Here is my Method2Representation class, I would like each row within the combobox to be equal to the toString behavior of the class Method2Representation. Here is the class below:

```
public class Method2Representation {
String methodid; 
String methodname;
List<Requirement2> requirements; 
public Method2Representation(String methodid, String methodname) {
    super();
    this.methodid = methodid;
    this.methodname = methodname;
}
public Method2Representation() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
public String getMethodid() {
    return methodid;
}
public void setMethodid(String methodid) {
    this.methodid = methodid;
}
public String getMethodname() {
    return methodname;
}
public void setMethodname(String methodname) {
    this.methodname = methodname;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Method2Representation [methodid=" + methodid + ", methodname=" + methodname + "]";
}
public List<Requirement2> getRequirements() {
    return requirements;
}
public void setRequirements(List<Requirement2> requirements) {
    this.requirements = requirements;
}
public Method2Representation(String methodid, String methodname, List<Requirement2> requirements) {
    super();
    this.methodid = methodid;
    this.methodname = methodname;
    this.requirements = requirements;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer to use Jface's `TableViewer` and `ComboBoxCellEditor` for cell editing.

But below is sample example for adding combo in `SWT Table` cell.

```
public class TableExmaple {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
    Table table = new Table(shell, SWT.BORDER | SWT.MULTI);
    table.setLinesVisible(true);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      TableColumn column = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
      column.setWidth(100);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
      new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
    }
    TableItem[] items = table.getItems();
    for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      TableEditor tableEditor = new TableEditor(table);
      CCombo combo = new CCombo(table, SWT.NONE);
      combo.setText("CCombo");
      combo.add("combo item 1");
      combo.add("combo item 2");
      tableEditor.grabHorizontal = true;
      tableEditor.setEditor(combo, items[i], 0);
      tableEditor = new TableEditor(table);
      Text text = new Text(table, SWT.NONE);
      text.setText("Text");
      tableEditor.grabHorizontal = true;
      tableEditor.setEditor(text, items[i], 1);
      tableEditor = new TableEditor(table);
      Button button = new Button(table, SWT.CHECK);
      button.pack();
      tableEditor.minimumWidth = button.getSize().x;
      tableEditor.horizontalAlignment = SWT.LEFT;
      tableEditor.setEditor(button, items[i], 2);
    }
    shell.pack();
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
      if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
  }
}
```